# TFS 2017 new web form editing

Tags: tfs

After upgrading to TFS 2017 (from 2015), I want to modify the new web forms to include the customizations that the 2015 version has.  However, when I export them using witadmin:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE> ./witadmin exportwitd /collection:myproj/coll /p:myproj /f:C:\Users\Me\Documents\foo.xml /n:Bug
```

I only get the old form - not the new form.  I'm running VS 2015 (ver 14), and have followed the [help pages](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/customize-wit-form), but cannot seem to export the new web form layout.  I can continue to use the old form, but at some point MS will deprecate that and force everyone to the new form.  I'd rather be ready than have to scramble!

I know I'm missing something easy, something right in front of my face, but any help in focusing me on the one tree would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using the VS2017 (v15.0) command line

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the [`WebLayout`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/weblayout-xml-elements) element within your work items. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/customize-wit-form). You may have to [enable the New Work Item Experience](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/manage-new-form-rollout#opt-in) first.

Comment: I've done that - the new work form is enabled (should have said that in the OP).  I've been using it for a couple of months, along with a few other admins.  And there is no WebLayout section in the XML after exporting, just the old Layout section.  I appreciate the response, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the migration tool does not automatically update (or even insert, in certain cases) the new layout.

When I did the migration I got a very (!) basic web layout, with only the system fields and the description.

Please see my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44001223/8019420). There I described my way for solving that problem.